# Google App Script - Classroom - Copy course

Tags: google-classroom

I want to copy a Classroom course with google app script. I can't find the method to do it.
I guess it would be something like "Classroom.Course.copy (....)"
can this be done?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### You can retrieve a Classroom and then create it with its parameters

Here's my approach:

First add the Advanced Service **Classroom** V1, then use the following code

```
function test() {
  var course = Classroom.Courses.get("ID");

  var newClass = {
    name: course.name,
    section: course.section,
    descriptionHeading: course.descriptionHeading,
    description: course.description,
    room: course.room,
    ownerId: course.ownerId,
    courseState: course.courseState
  };

  Classroom.Courses.create(newClass)
}
```

If you are not sure about the Course ID simply list all your classrooms by using [Method: courses.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list).

Once you've done this, copy the writable values in order to create the new classroom.

**NOTE: most of the courses fields are read-only, that's why there's no explicit method to copy the entire course**

### References

- [Resource: Course](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses#resource:-course)
- [Method: courses.create](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/create)
- [Method: courses.get](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/get)
- [Method: courses.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list)